# Realm with React Native, how to query through list objects

Tags: database, mobile, react-native, realm

I noticed this question ([Use React Native Realm to Query through multiple List Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39671131/6019768)) but was unable to get my query to work with the provided answer from @blackpla9ue.

I have the following schemas/models, and I want to query where ProductReview->productId is equal to 123, and Review->reviewText contains "a simple string".

This query simply returns all reviews for productId 123.

```
let allReviews = realm.objects('ProductReview', 'productId = "123");
let reviews = allReviews.filtered('reviews.reviewText CONTAINS[c] "a simple string"');
```

I have also tried removing `'productId = "123"'` which simply results in all product reviews being returned for all products. It seems to either be completely ignoring `filtered` or I am missing something.

```js
class ProductReview extends Realm.Object{}
ProductReview.schema = {
  name: 'ProductReview',
  primaryKey: 'productId',
  properties: {
      productId: 'string',
      averageRating: 'float',
      totalReviewCount: 'int',
      reviews: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Review'},

  }
}

class Review extends Realm.Object{}
Review.schema = {
   name: 'Review',
   properties: {
     rating: 'float',
     title: {type: 'string', optional: true},
     reviewText: {type: 'string', optional: true},
     userLocation: {type: 'string', optional: true},
     userNickName: {type: 'string', optional: true},
     tags: {type: 'list', objectType: 'StringList'}
   }
}
```

Looking to see what I might be doing wrong here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#filtering), it seems to me that the query you're possibly looking for is

```
let allReviews = realm.objects('ProductReview');
let reviews = allReviews.filtered(
                 'productId = "123" AND reviews.reviewText CONTAINS[c] "a simple string"');
```

Comment: Hi @EpicPandaForce, thanks for the response. So, basically this gets me half way there, by only giving me the Products that have reviews that have "a simple string". But I also get ALL the reviews for that productId. What I've learned about Realm is that it does return only the filtered items of nested list objects. Because there is not (currently) and easy way to say give me ALL reviews with "a simple string" that is IN parent "productId" unless you actually have that in your reviews list object as a reference. Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: That query should work for what you are trying to do. @forstertime do you have some sample data you can share that could be used to reproduce the problem? If so feel free to send it to help@realm.io and we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

**In Realm**

[Full Text Search in React-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348606/full-text-search-in-react-native/58645819#58645819)

**Working**

```
    realm = new Realm({
        schema: [StudentScheme]
    })
    const object1 = realm.objects('Student_Info');

    obj_filtered = object1.filtered("student_name CONTAINS $0" ,search );



    $0 second object $1 third object $2  .... etc
```

**like this**

```
 let filteredData;
        if(search==undefined){
            filteredData = mydata.filtered('student_name CONTAINS ""');
        }else {
            //filteredData = mydata.filtered("student_name CONTAINS $0" ,search );
            filteredData = mydata.filtered("student_name CONTAINS $0 OR student_subject CONTAINS $1  OR student_class CONTAINS $2 " ,search ,search ,search);
        }
```