# Full Text Search in React-native

Tags: sqlite, react-native, react-native-ios

React native noob here , 
I wanna know if  it's possible to use the FullTextSearch feature of sqlite in react, if so , tell me where i can learn more about it .
Thanks !

Comment: What you actually want to do. why you need to sqlite to search test

Comment: I have a large collection  of text documents (29,000) ( mostly medecine SPC files) I want to  make it possible for users to search for a keyword in those files, All text document follow the same structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Realm Database for React Native**, 
Realm is an object-oriented database. OO model makes it 10x faster than SQLite and saves you from running tons of query which is a common thing for a typical SQL database
and **fuse.js** may help you to search text.

Answer (score 0):

```
    realm = new Realm({
        schema: [StudentScheme]
    })

    const mydata = realm.objects('Product_Info');

    let filteredData = [];

    let keywords = search.split(" ");

    keywords.forEach((obj, index) => {
        let databaseSearchResult = mydata.filtered("prodName LIKE[c] $0 OR prodDesc LIKE[c] $0", "*" + obj + "*")
        Object.keys(databaseSearchResult).map(key => {
            filteredData.push(databaseSearchResult[key])
        })
    });

           <SearchBar
                placeholder="Type Here..."
                onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
                value={this.state.search}
            />
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.filteredData}
                renderItem={this.rowRenderer}
                keyExtractor={(item, key) => key}
            />
```

=====================================================================

```
updateSearch = search => {
    this.setState({search: search}, () => this.searchText(search.trim()));
};

searchText = (search) => {

    console.log("   Detail Activity  ------------- search -->" + search);

    realm = new Realm({
        schema: [StudentScheme]
    })
    const mydata = realm.objects('Product_Info');

    let filteredData = {};

    let keywords = search.split(" ");


     keywords.forEach((obj, index) => {
        let databaseSearchResult = mydata.filtered("prodName LIKE[c] $0 OR 
                                 prodDesc LIKE[c] $0", "*" + obj + "*")

        Object.keys(databaseSearchResult).map(key => {
            filteredData[`${Object.keys(filteredData).length}`] = 
                                                   databaseSearchResult[key]
        })
    });

    this.setState({
        filteredData
    }, () => {
         console.log('Search-------------------------------FILTER DATA', this.state.filteredData)

        let dataProvider = new DataProvider((r1, r2) => r1 !== r2)

        let updatedDataProvider=dataProvider.cloneWithRows(filteredData)
        this.setState({dataProvider: updatedDataProvider},()=>{
             console.log("CALLBACKK ", this.state.dataProvider)
        })

    })
}

            <SearchBar
                placeholder="Type Here..."
                onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
                value={this.state.search}
            />

            {
                Object.keys(this.state.filteredData).map((key)=>(
                    this.rowRenderer(null, this.state.filteredData[key])
                ))
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Realm = require('realm');

let realm;


let dataProvider = new DataProvider((r1, r2) => r1 !== r2)
realm = new Realm({
    schema: [StudentScheme]
})



    state = {
        search: '',
        dataProvider: new DataProvider((r1, r2) => r1 !== r2).cloneWithRows({}),
        filteredData: {}
    };

    updateSearch = search => {
        this.setState({search: search}, () => this.searchText(search.trim()));
    };

    searchText = (search) => {
        console.log("   Detail Activity  ------------- search -->" + search);

        const mydata = realm.objects('Product_Info');

        let filteredData = [];

        let keywords = search.split(" ");

        keywords.forEach((obj, index) => {

            let databaseSearchResult = mydata.filtered("prodName LIKE[c] $0 OR prodDesc LIKE[c] $0 OR prodPrice LIKE[c]  $0 ", "*" + obj + "*" )

            Object.keys(databaseSearchResult).map(key => {
                filteredData.push(databaseSearchResult[key])
            })

        });

        this.setState({
            filteredData
        }, () => {
            console.log('Search-------------------------------FILTER DATA \n', this.state.filteredData)

            console.log('Search-------------------------------FILTER DATA--------------- \n');
        })
    }


    fetchDB = () => {
        var mydata = realm.objects('Product_Info');

        this.setState({dataProvider: dataProvider.cloneWithRows(mydata), filteredData: mydata})          //TODO ...
    }



        <FlatList
            data={this.state.filteredData}
            renderItem={this.rowRenderer}
            keyExtractor={(item, key) => key}
            />
```